# JavaScript play RAW audio bytes/stream

Tags: javascript, audio, raw

Can I play RAW audio bytes (parts of audio stream) in JavaScript continuously? I will be sending the stream in parts to JavaScript to some buffer and then the JavaScript will be playing it.

Here is example of the RAW audio bytes (part of audio stream):

```
\x98\x99\x9a\x9b\x9e\xe9\xe7\xe0\xe3\xde
```

Comment: If you're using streams than you'd be able to play audio through a [`MediaStreamAudioSourceNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamAudioSourceNode). It is able to receive a `MediaStream` object and pass it to the speakers. As long as your audio is a supported audio format then it should work.

Comment: Thank you a lot, but, to which format I must convert my linear RAW audio? When I want to use "audioContext.decodeAudioData..." it says "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The buffer passed to decodeAudioData contains an unknown content type."

Comment: Check this [web audio codec guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Audio_codecs) to learn what codecs and formats are supported on the web.

Comment: Thanks! And if I have the supported codec, then how can I play the raw bytes? Is there any proven procedure how to play them?

Comment: The node referred in the first comment is the best way to play a stream. But it'll be easier to say if you could include some of your code to the question to see how you're implementing your stream.

Comment: Check out [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74751390/what-is-the-best-way-to-stream-audio-to-the-browser-chunk-by-chunk-with-javacr/74768868#74768868](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74751390/what-is-the-best-way-to-stream-audio-to-the-browser-chunk-by-chunk-with-javacr/74768868#74768868), the question explores sending raw pcm data, and ends up choosing mp3 as the streaming format